# Error: The value is only allowed in Mobile Configuration Filters

Tags: custom-report-type

I want to display `All Cases owned by user, grouped by Status` using Standard Reports. 
I selected `Cases` from `Customer Support Reports` folder and applied a filter `Case Owner` `equals $User.Id` for cases owned by Logged in user. And its showing an error as under:

```
Error: The value $User.Id is only allowed in Mobile Configuration Filters
```

Please let me know if anything I'm doing wrong or there's anything to do with Mobile Configuration Filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the report builder page, instead of applying this criteria, you can always select "My Cases" to display the cases owned by logged in user.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Amit it worked for me :) Just wanted to ask when to use the $User variable then.

Comment: Ex - VF Pages, Email Templates